# $\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\sin^{3}(x)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\sin^{3}(x)}dx$$

So I tried with $u=\tan(x/2)$ but I get some heavy results.Also I tried to factorize sin then to write $\sin^{2}x$ like $1-\cos^{2}x$ then to use $u=\cos x$ but the results are too heavy.

How to approach this integral?

Comment: what about a substitution of $ \tan u=\sin x$? i.e. First do a substitution of $v=\sin x \ $ then $ \ u=\tan^{-1}{v}$?

Comment: Hint: Multiply the denominator and the numerator by $\sin x$ then rewrite the denominator in terms of $\cos x$ and substitute $\cos x=t$ to get $\int_0^\frac12 \frac{dt}{(1-t^2)(2-t^2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

\begin{align} 
\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sin x+\sin^3 x}dx &= \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{\sin x} -\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^2 x}\right)dx\\
& =  \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\csc xdx  +\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{2-\cos^2 x}d(\cos x)\\
& =  \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\csc xdx  +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-\cos x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\cos x}\right)d(\cos x)
\end{align}

Can you complete it now?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the integral as

$$I =
\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin xdx}{\sin^2x(1+\sin^2 x)}=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d(\cos x)}{(1-\cos^2x)(2-\cos^2 x)}$$

and let $t= \cos x$,

$$I =  \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)(2-t^2)}
=\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dt}{1-t^2}-\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{dt}{2-t^2}$$
$$=\tanh^{-1}t|_0^{1/2}-\frac1{\sqrt2}\tanh^{-1}\frac t{\sqrt2}\bigg|_0^{1/2}$$
$$=\tanh^{-1}\frac12-\frac1{\sqrt2}\tanh^{-1}\frac1{2\sqrt2}$$

where $(\tanh^{-1}t)'=\frac1{1-t^2}$ is used.